# Find Duplicate Identifier Across Multiple Rows As Key In MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

We have a huge issue with duplicate products that I'm trying to find using MySQL, our database is simply to huge to go through manually. I need to find duplicate products, here is the best description that I can give you right now.

It's about WordPress and WooCommerce. I need to find duplicate products that have the same meta_value of meta_key 's : **_sku** and **_price**.

The same table has **post_id** which reference to the product in **wp_posts**, which is where the products need to be deleted, for now we can leave the meta in the database, shouldn't do any harm for now.

At first I tried finding duplicates using the post_title, but the problem is that some titles are different, and we have some products with the same SKU but with a different title, that's why we are matching on the _sku and _price meta_key's.

```
Relevant Tables | columns:
wp_postmeta | post_id, meta_key, meta_value
wp_posts | ID, post_title

Example data:
wp_postmeta | 15, _price, 15.00
wp_postmeta | 15, _sku, "DUP"
wp_postmeta | 16, _price, 15.00
wp_postmeta | 16, _sku, "DUP"
wp_postmeta | 17, _price, 42.00
wp_postmeta | 17, _sku, "VALID"
wp_posts | 15, "This is a duplicate product." (delete either this one or one below)
wp_posts | 16, "This is another product, same values."
wp_posts | 17, "This is a valid single, product."
```

Comment: Please show us some sample data to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added some sample data to illustrate the problem, can't wrap my head around how I should approach this so any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shold loop for all products and if found duplicate, then trigger following queries.

Replace product_id by duplicate product id of loop.

DELETE p FROM wp_posts p WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND ID = product_id;

DELETE pm FROM wp_postmeta pm LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.post_id WHERE wp.ID = product_id;

DELETE tr FROM wp_term_relationships tr INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) WHERE tt.taxonomy != 'link_category' AND tr.object_id IN = product_id;

Comment: Is this not possible using only a MySQL query? Just to find the duplicates and delete them in wp_posts? I can cleanup the terms afterwards using WooCommerce tools.

Comment: While I think it is possible to do GROUP_CONCAT on the meta_values and afterwards check for duplicates right?